# Density of Y = log(X) for Gamma-distributed X

Tags: density-function, gamma-distribution

This question is closely related to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7969/how-to-quickly-sample-x-if-expx-gamma)

Suppose I have a random variable $X \sim \text{Gamma}(k, \theta)$, and I define $Y = \log(X)$. I would like to find the probability density function of $Y$.

I had originally thought I would just define cumulative distribution function X, do a change of variable, and take the "inside" of the integral as my density, like so,

\begin{align}
P(X \le c) & = \int_{0}^{c} \frac{1}{\theta^k} \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)} x^{k- 1} e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}} dx \\
P(Y \le \log c) & = \int_{\log(0)}^{\log(c)} \frac{1}{\theta^k} \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)} \exp(y)^{k- 1} e^{-\frac{\exp(y)}{\theta}} \exp(y) dy \\
\end{align}

Here I use $y = \log x$ and $dy = \frac{1}{x} dx$, then sub in definitions for $x$ and $dx$ in terms of $y$.

The output, unfortunately, does not integrate to 1.  I'm not sure where my mistake is. Could some tell me where my error is?

Comment: If you work through the cdf, you should not change the integrand from the first to the second integral. Your mistake is in trying to use both the cdf and the Jacobian approaches at the same time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write the densities with the indicators to have a clear picture.

If $X\sim\mathrm{Gamma}(k,\theta)$, then
$$
  f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\theta^k \Gamma(k)} \;\; x^{k-1} e^{-x/\theta} \, I_{(0,\infty)}(x) \, .
$$

If $Y=g(X)=\log X$, with inverse $X=h(Y)=e^Y$, then
$$
  f_Y(y) = f_X(h(y)) |h'(y)| = \frac{1}{\theta^k\Gamma(k)} \;\; \exp\left( ky-e^y/\theta\right)\,I_{(-\infty,\infty)}(y) \, ,
$$
and the CDF is obtained from the definition
$$
  P(Y\leq y) = \int_{-\infty}^y f_Y(t) \,dt \, .
$$

Comment: This is a good answer, but maybe you should parameterize the Gamma distribution in the same way as the original question.

Comment: Good point, Max. Done.

Comment: Woops, my own definitions had bugs.  Should be $\alpha = k$.