# Using the rejection sampling with the method of inversion

Tags: r, monte-carlo, computational-statistics

I am hoping to write some rejection algorithm code in R to approximate a $\text{Gamma}(k,\lambda)$ distribution.

The problem is more for educational purposes than real-world implementation.

Given an $\text{Exponential}(\lambda)$ distribution with PDF:

$$f_{\lambda}(x) = \lambda\text{exp}(-\lambda x)$$

the CDF can be expressed as:

$$F_{\lambda}(x) = 1 - \text{exp}(-\lambda x)$$

where $x>0$ and $\lambda>0$.

And the inverse of the CDF can be expressed as:

$$F^{-1}(U) = -\text{log}(1-U)/\lambda$$

where $U$ is a random number generated such that: $U \sim \text{U}[0,1]$.

Assuming that:

$$X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots, X_{k} \stackrel{\text{ iid }}{ \sim }\text{Exponential}(\lambda)$$

and:

$$Y = X_{1} + X_{2} + \dots + X_{k}$$

then:

$$Y \sim \text{Gamma}(k, \lambda)$$

Now, the above approach for simulating a $\text{Gamma}(k,\lambda)$ from a sum of $k$  $\text{Exponential}(\lambda)$ random variables will, naturally, only work where $k \in {\bf N}$, but let's assume the objective is to simulate $\text{Gamma}(k,\lambda)$ where $k \notin {\bf N}$.
It has been suggested to use an accept-reject approach with an envelope function being the $\text{Gamma}(\lfloor{k}\rfloor,\lambda-1)$ density,
where $\lfloor{k}\rfloor$ is the function `floor(k)`.

**EDIT:**

In the above example, it's clear that target distribution is given by:

$$f(x) = \frac{\lambda^{k}}{\Gamma(k)}x^{k-1}e^{-\lambda x}$$

But in order to solidify these concepts, could somebody provide the form of the simulating distribution ($h(x)$), the envelope function ($g(x) = M*h(x)$) and, of course, the optimal value of $M$?

Solidifying these ideas would really help me out.

#### Closely related

[Rejection sampling for a modified Gamma distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13767)

[How to quickly sample X if exp(X) ~ Gamma?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7969/how-to-quickly-sample-x-if-expx-gamma) (one answer provides a clever `R` implementation).

Comment: I am afraid there is some confusion there about the nature of the accept-reject method. For one thing, you cannot use an exponential to approximate Gamma distributions with $\alpha<1$. For another, the idea of using a sum of $n$ exponential variates will produce a Gamma$(n,\lambda)$ variate. I suggest you look at our Example 2.19 (page 52) in our [Monte Carlo Statistical Methods book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1441919392/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1441919392&linkCode=as2&tag=chrprobboo-20) with George Casella.

Comment: (followed from above) Precisely, I do not understand your remark about $f(x)<x\sim G(\alpha,\beta)$. This is not the standard condition: $u<f(x)/Mg(x)$. Inversion is an altogether different method: do you want to use it for simulating the exponential? It is trivial: $X=-\log(U)/\lambda\sim E(\lambda)$ is **de facto** an inversion.

Comment: @Xi'an, thanks for your input.
My apologies. As you can probably tell, this area is brand new to me,  and, originally, the question was very poorly constructed; since then, I have revised the question. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: This is the example we detail in our book, indeed.

Comment: @Xi'an, fantastic! I'll be sure to check it out!
It must be a common example.
Thanks again!

Comment: @whuber. Sorry about the re-edit. I forgot to re-include the linked questions.

Comment: I do not understand why you move from $\lambda$ to $\lambda-1$...

Comment: @Xi'an: The method of inversion and rejection sampling was discussed in a class that I was taking and the envelope function suggested for this example adhered to $\text{Gamma}(\lfloor{k}\rfloor, \lambda-1)$.
Beyond this, I cannot really provide the motivation. Like I said, this is all very new to me. Sorry.

Comment: I suggest using a $G(\lfloor k \rfloor,\beta)$ with $\beta<\lambda$ and trying to optimise in $\beta$ to get the highest possible acceptance rate. (Again, this is detailed in our book.)

Comment: @Xi'an: I have made one final edit to the above question. If you could provide some final assistance on the topic, I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the target density
$$
f(x) = \frac{\lambda^{k}}{\Gamma(k)}x^{k-1}e^{-\lambda x} \quad k>1
$$
let us write $k_0=\lfloor{k}\rfloor$ and take as envelope density
$$
g(x) = \frac{\lambda_0^{k_0}}{\Gamma(k_0)}x^{k_0-1}e^{-\lambda_0 x}
$$
with $\lambda_0>0$. Then the ratio $f/g$ is given by
$$
\frac{\lambda^{k}}{\Gamma(k)}\,\frac{\Gamma(k_0)}{\lambda_0^{k_0}}\,
x^{k-k_0}\,e^{-(\lambda -\lambda_0)x}
$$
which is bounded in 0 because $k-k_0\ge 0$ and at $+\infty$ when $\lambda -\lambda_0>0$. Under this assumption, the maximum is obtained at $x^*$ solution of
$$
\frac{k-k_0}{x} = \lambda -\lambda_0
$$
by taking the derivative of the ratio. Therefore
$$
x^* = \frac{k-k_0}{\lambda -\lambda_0}
$$
and
\begin{align*}
M &= f(x^*)/g(x^*)\\ &=
\frac{\lambda^{k}}{\Gamma(k)}\,\frac{\Gamma(k_0)}{\lambda_0^{k_0}}\,
(x^*)^{k-k_0}\,e^{-(\lambda -\lambda_0)x^*}\\ &=
\frac{\lambda^{k}}{\Gamma(k)}\,\frac{\Gamma(k_0)}{\lambda_0^{k_0}}\,
(x^*)^{k-k_0}\,e^{-(k-k_0)} 
\end{align*}
i.e.
$$
M = 
\frac{\lambda^{k}}{\Gamma(k)}\,\frac{\Gamma(k_0)}{\lambda_0^{k_0}}\,
(x^*/e)^{k-k_0}
$$
As described in Example 2.19 (page 52) in our [Monte Carlo Statistical Methods book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441919392) with George Casella, you can further optimise the choice of $\lambda_0$ by minimising $M$ in $\lambda_0$, which leads to $\lambda_0/k_0=\lambda=k$, i.e.
$$
\lambda_0=\frac{k_0\lambda}{k}
$$

Comment: Do you mean $\lambda_0/k_0=\lambda/k$ near the end there, rather than $\lambda_0/k_0=\lambda=k$?